# how to get a box from its inner shape using cv2 (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, shapes

I'm trying to detect objects and text in a hand-drawn diagram.

My goal is to be able to "parse" something like this into an object structure for further processing. My first aim is to detect text, lines (with or without arrows) and boxes.

I can do contour analysis to find a circle, but my issue is that the circle are connected with its inner text. I need some help to separate the circle with its text.

[image: a box with text 'v1']

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys

points = set()

import math

def dup(cX, cY):
    for p in list(points):
        dx = p[0] - cX
        dy = p[1] - cY
        if math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) <= 4:
            return True
    return False
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    src = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
    if isinstance(src, type(None)):
        sys.exit()
    img = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    height, width = img.shape[:2]
    imgarea = height * width
    minarea = imgarea * 0.001
    _, th = cv2.threshold(img, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv2.imshow("th", th)
    
    if len(sys.argv) >= 4:
        thin = cv2.Canny(th, 50, 150)
        cv2.imshow("thinning", thin)
    elif len(sys.argv) >= 3:
        thin = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(~th)
        cv2.imshow("thinning", thin)
    else:
        thin = th

    contours, h = cv2.findContours(thin, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )
    c = (251,0,0)
    colors = [c, None]
    def findColors(i, h, colors):
        if colors[i]:
            return colors[i]
        else:
            colors.append(None)
            next, prev, firstc, parent = h
            if prev >= 0:
                c = colors[i] = colors[prev]
            else:
                assert parent != -1
                colors[i] = colors[parent]
                r,g,b = colors[i]
                if g < 200: g += 50
                else: b += 50
                c = colors[i] = (g,r,b)
                
            return c

    for i, cnt in enumerate(contours):
        print(i, h[0][i], end=' ')
        color = findColors(i, h[0][i], colors)
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        cv2.drawContours(src,[cnt],0,color,2)
        cv2.imshow('img',src)
        key = chr(cv2.waitKey(0))
        print(color)
        
        if len(cnt) == 4 or area < minarea:
            continue
        
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
        la = len(approx)
        M = cv2.moments(cnt)
        if M["m00"] != 0:  # prevent divide by zero
            cX = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]))
            cY = int((M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
            if (cX, cY) in points or dup(cX, cY):
                print('Dup', cX, cY, la, ' == ' , area)
                continue
            else:
                points.add( (cX, cY) )
            
        hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt) #shape = sd.detect(c)
        perimeter = cv2.arcLength(hull, True)
        if perimeter < 1.0: continue
        harea = cv2.contourArea(hull)
        if harea < minarea: continue
        if harea > area * 1.3:
            print('Big hull? ', harea, area)
            continue
        circularity = (4 * 3.14159265 * area) / (perimeter * perimeter)
        unknown = False

        if la<=5 and la >= 3:
            if circularity > 0.75:
                print("square", circularity, cX, cY, la, ' == ' , area)
                box = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
                cv2.rectangle(src, box, (0, 255, 121), 5);
                cv2.drawContours(src,[cnt],0,(255,126,0),2)
            elif circularity > 0.57:
                print("triangle", circularity, cX, cY, la, area) 
            else:
                print("???", la) 
                points.remove( (cX, cY) )
                cv2.drawContours(src,[cnt],0,(121,61,255),2)
                unknown = True
        elif la > 5:
            if circularity > 0.9:
                print("circle", circularity, cX, cY, la, area) 
                center, radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
                ct = (int(center[0]), int(center[1]))
                cv2.circle(src, ct, int(radius), (0,111,255), 2)
            else:
                print("??", circularity, cX, cY, la, area) 
                points.remove( (cX, cY) )
                cv2.drawContours(src,[cnt],0,(0,111,255),2)
                unknown = True
            
        if key == ' ':  #zoom
            print(approx, hull)
        elif key == 'w': #wipe the contour
            cv2.drawContours(src,[cnt],0,(255,255,255),2)
        elif key == 'q': #quit
            break

    cv2.imshow('img',src)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: As I got this, you can do this even without using contours explicitly. First threshold to get the latter and surrounding circle to foreground. Then go horizontally and vertically, where you replace last and first consecutive 1s' set with 0s'. [Note : For this method works the letter cannot join with the circle at any point.]

Comment: Thank you for giving me a method. But the letter joins with the circle in my case.

Comment: find the outer circular contour. fill it. you have a mask. erode the mask as much as you expect circles to be thick. use mask to erase circle. inner part remains.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.